# How do I secure access to servers without corporate network?

Tags: networking, security

My company is distributed and does not have a "network" per se.  We use AWS  and I need to ensure we have secure access to the environments but I can't do that by allowing users to VPN into the corporate network then access the server environment.  What is an appropriate solution to securing the server environment given the fact that the whole workforce is distributed?

Comment: Run a VPN somewhere in the cloud, require people to do all management via the VPN?  Perhaps use distributed VPN like Tinc?

Comment: Is vpn enough absent a corp network?

Comment: Dunno, depends on your requirements. A VPN can give you strong authentication, and encryption of data in transport.  So may be good enough But if you need some kind of auditing like you might require for PCI-DCC, SOX, HIPAA or something else, maybe not.  It isn't like there is one true answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest setting up an SSH bastion host.  You will want to give it an Elastic IP and set up your security groups to properly limit the access afforded the bastion host.

Some considerations:

- enforce SSH keys.  (no password auth)
- configure fail2ban to weed out the brute force attempts
- closely limit the inbound and outbound ports available for the b-h
- corporate policy requiring a password on ssh private keys

Major downside is that your users will need to be proficient in SSH tunneling.

In any event, you would want a bastion host available for disaster recovery - i.e. VPN falls down.